# Why would container div contents be pushed below the div?

Tags: css

Basically I am trying to have a circular border around the emoji, that is inside of span, in a container div.

The 50% radius border should display on hover, which it does but the contents in the span are pushed below the div. See the screenshot.

```
<div className={styles.emojiContainer} key={index} >
   <span className={styles.emoji} role="img" aria-label={feeling} onClick={handleClick} ></span>
   <p>happy</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.emojiContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;

  p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
}

.emoji {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
}

.emoji:hover {
  border: 4px solid #2773e2;
}
```

[image: emoji hover]

Comment: `.emoji { line-height: 3.9rem; ....`

Comment: Thanks, that got closer but it was still off by several pixels and I couldn't get it quite right. I found using hover and adding a text shadow worked better.

Answer (score 0):

It worked better to just add a text-shadow:

```
.emoji:hover {
  text-shadow: 4px 0 #2773e2, -3px 0 #2773e2, 0 4px #2773e2, 0 -4px #2773e2,
               3px 3px #2773e2, -3px -3px #2773e2, 3px -3px #2773e2, -3px 3px #2773e2;
}
```